# arcgis api can't connect to wmts which has secret key

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api, esri-javascript-api

arcgis api for js can't connect to wmts sever with  secret key

the wmts sever increas Adding Key Verification

before update：

```
 url："http://t0.tianditu.gov.cn/img_c/wmts"
```

after update:

```
url："http://t0.tianditu.gov.cn/img_c/wmts?tk=your secret key"
```

my secret key is:

```
8447f500c6f2b44fe8ddd3acccad4f38
```

so the new request is:

```
url："http://t0.tianditu.gov.cn/img_c/wmts?tk=8447f500c6f2b44fe8ddd3acccad4f38"
```

my arcgis code is:

```
var layers=new WMTSLayer({
  url:"http://t0.tianditu.gov.cn/img_c/wmts?tk=8447f500c6f2b44fe8ddd3acccad4f38"
      });
```

but the chrome still request:

```
http://t0.tianditu.gov.cn/img_c/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml
```

without secret key request:

```
?tk=8447f500c6f2b44fe8ddd3acccad4f38
```

the right url should be:

```
http://t0.tianditu.gov.cn/img_c/wmts?tk=8447f500c6f2b44fe8ddd3acccad4f38/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml
```

how to write to let api request the url add secret key
like:

```
http://t0.tianditu.gov.cn/img_c/wmts?tk=8447f500c6f2b44fe8ddd3acccad4f38/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml
```

Comment: Hi Mikesui! Welcome to stack overflow! Please note that this is a public website, and API keys are not safe here, please fake or hide the key asap.

Comment: the API key just for test

Answer (score 1):

You should put your token inside the `customParamaters` like this:

```
var layers=new WMTSLayer({
  url:"http://t0.tianditu.gov.cn/img_c/wmts",
  customParameters: {
    tk: "8447f500c6f2b44fe8ddd3acccad4f38"
  }
});
```

**For API v4.x:**

- https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-WMTSLayer.html#customParameters

**For API v3.x**:

- https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/wmtslayer-amd.html#customparameters

> customParametersObject
>
> Use this to append custom parameters to all WMTS requests. The custom parameters are applied to GetCapabilities and GetTile. For
>   example, if an access key is required, the key can be configured as a
>   custom parameter.